# No such file or directory:'main.ui' in cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyqt5, executable, cx-freeze

I used PyQT5 to develop a software using python.
now i have main.ui and main.py
i've used this command line to read main.ui file:

```
FORM_CLASS,_=loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__),"main.ui"))
```

now my main.ui is connected to my main.py file where main python code is written.

I also created setup.py as per cx_freeze instruction

Then I've used cmd command:

```
python setup.py build_exe
```

once completed i have received below error:

```
No such file or directory:'main.ui'
```

so ho i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use external resources then you should use the cx_freeze manual for [data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files):

> Using data files Applications often need data files besides the code,
> such as icons. Using a setup script, you can list data files or
> directories in the include_files option to build_exe. They’ll be
> copied to the build directory alongside the executable. Then to find
> them, use code like this:
>
> ```
> def find_data_file(filename):
>     if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
>         # The application is frozen
>         datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
>     else:
>         # The application is not frozen
>         # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
>         datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
>     return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
> ```
>
> An alternative is to embed data in code, for example by using Qt’s
> resource system.

So in your case modify your code to:

```
import os.path
import sys
# ...

def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)

# ...

FORM_CLASS,_=loadUiType(find_data_file("main.ui"))

# ...
```

And change the setup.py to include the .ui:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name="mytest",
    version="0.1",
    description="",
    options={"build_exe": {"include_files": "main.ui"}},
    executables=[Executable("main.py")],
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother it works for me, using your method , appreciated ..